# Can't import as null value SQL Server 2008 TSV file

Tags: sql-server

I import data from a TSV file with SQL Server 2008.

null is replaced by 0 when I confirm a table after import　with integer column.

How to import as null, please Help me!!

Comment: you mean csv???

Comment: TSV = Tab Separated Values.

Comment: What technique are you using to import the file?  BCP, Bulk Insert, SSIS?

Comment: derrrr.. i knew that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you are using a BULK INSERT, did you specify the KEEPNULLS parameter?

```
BULK INSERT MyTestDefaultCol2
FROM 'C:\importin.txt'
WITH (
  DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
  KEEPNULLS
);
```

[MSDN SQL SERVER DEV CENTER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx)